# Como abrir um video no youtube com react native?

Tags: android, react, react-native

Estou desenvolvendo um programa android em react native no qual, ao usuário clicar em um botão um vídeo no aplicativo youtube será aberto, porem não faco ideia de como integrar outros programas ao meu